# How to check if values in one dataframe exist in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops

Suppose we have a data frame like this:

```
id  reply  user_name
1   NA     John
2   NA     Amazon
3   NA     Bob
```

And another data frame like this:

```
name  organisation
John  Amazon
Pat   Apple
```

Is there a way to fill in the `reply` column in the first data frame with `'True'` or `'False'` if the values in column 3 match either columns 1 or 2 in the second data frame? So for example, since `John` and `Amazon` from the second data frame exist in the first data frame, I want the first data frame to update as so:

```
id  reply  user_name
1   True   John
2   True   Amazon
3   False  Bob
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this using `%in%` and a vector for all values:

```
#Code
df1$reply <- df1$user_name %in% c(df2$name,df2$organisation)
```

Output:

```
df1
  id reply user_name
1  1  TRUE      John
2  2  TRUE    Amazon
3  3 FALSE       Bob
```

Some data used:

```
#Data1
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, reply = c(NA, NA, NA), user_name = c("John", 
"Amazon", "Bob")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))

#Data2
df2 <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Pat"), organisation = c("Amazon", 
"Apple")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the output I want, but when I try with the full dataset I get this error: `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, reply, value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 221711`. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: The names are different in my original dataset yes, but I edited the code to match the names. The `reply` column in the data here is a logical type in the full dataset.

Comment: @HelpMe Try with `df1$reply[is.na(df1$reply)] <- df1$user_name %in% c(df2$name,df2$organisation)`

Comment: all values in the column are NA only

Comment: Using your `is.na` solution, I get a different error message: `replacement has length zero`. Any ideas why this would occur?

Comment: Thank you. I don't appear to have the option to create a new chat with you following those instructions. Could you invite me instead?

Comment: It's the same as yours but relevant to the dataset I am using (so different names). Not sure if it'll be useful, but this is it: `subset_files_tweets$in_reply_to_screen_name_in[is.na(subset_files_tweets$in_reply_to_screen_name_in)] <- subset_files_tweets$in_reply_to_screen %in% c(cand_info$party_name_full, cand_info$screenName)`

Comment: Oh, my bad - one of the columns was named incorrectly. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%` in `base R`

```
df1$reply <- df1$user_name %in%  unlist(df2)
```

If we want to change the format of the logical to character string

```
df1$reply <- sub("^(.)(.*)", "\\1\\L\\2", df1$reply, perl = TRUE)
df1$reply
#[1] "True"  "True"  "False"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3, reply = c(NA, NA, NA), user_name = c("John", 
"Amazon", "Bob")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))

df2 <- structure(list(name = c("John", "Pat"), organisation = c("Amazon", 
"Apple")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get the exact output you're looking for with 3 lines of code!

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, reply = NA, user.name = c("John", "Amazon", "Bob"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:2, name = c("John", "Pat"), organisation = c("Amazon", "Apple"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df1$reply <- df1$user.name %in%  unlist(df2) %>% as.character() %>% str_to_title()
```

Output

```
id reply user.name
 1  True      John
 2  True    Amazon
 3 False       Bob
```

You will need the packages `dplyr`, `magrittr`, and `stringr`, which I highly recommend for data wrangling of all kinds.

Answer (score 0):

Building off the first answer, you can also solve this in a tidy way too.

```
#Building your dataframes
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:3, reply = NA, user.name = c("John", "Amazon", "Bob"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:2, name = c("John", "Pat"), organisation = c("Amazon", "Apple"), stringsAsFactors = F)


  df1 %>%
    mutate(reply = user.name %in% c(df2$name, df2$organisation))
```

I like personally the tidy solution because then you can easily pipe through the result to get more insights--for instance, if you want to know how many people replied, that just takes one more line:

```
  df1 %>%
    mutate(reply = user.name %in% c(df2$name, df2$organisation)) %>%
    summarize(reply_sum = sum(reply))
```